# conditional AC_OUTPUT

Tags: distribution, autotools, autoconf

I would like to maintain a configure file that generates a different set of Makefiles, depends on what flags the configure script was given. To be more specific, I want `make dist` to generate a subset of all the directories in the project.

For example, suppose I have directories `project/a project/b, project/c` with Makefile.am's and all other necessary stuff to enable compiling the project using `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make`. Now, suppose I want to omit the directories `project/b project/c` from the distribution tarball. I tried the following:

```
AS_IF([test "x$for_dist" == "xyes"], 
      [CONDITIONAL_MAKEFILES=""], 
      [CONDITIONAL_MAKEFILES="b/Makefile c/Makefile"]
)

AC_OUTPUT(Makefile a/Makefile ${CONDITIONAL_MAKEFILES})
```

This won't work, I get `config.status: error: cannot find input file: b/Makefile.in`.  If I specify the output Makefiles without a variable, it works fine.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution-

Using `AC_CONFIG_FILES` rather than `AC_OUTPUT` enables more flexibility. For example, referring to the above example:

```
AS_IF([test "x$for_dist" == "xyes"], [AC_CONFIG_FILES(b/Makefile c/Makefile)] )

AC_OUTPUT(Makefile a/Makefile)
```

This will output three Makefiles in case `for_dist` has the value `yes`, and will output only one Makefile otherwise.

Comment: This is true in general, but in my specific case I had to omit some of the sources.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I wonder if it might be easier to set `DIST_SUBDIRS` explicitly? The 'forked' distribution could also `test -d ${srcdir}/b` to ignore `for_dist` settings.

Comment: Regarding `DIST_SUBDIRS`- I've read that it should be used to "distribute directories that are not to be built". However, regarding the `test -d ${srcdir}/b` - Can you elaborate?